# Shuffle.js - resize images on applying filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to resize my images when filter is applied.
Currently I have the following:

```
Demo.prototype.addShuffleEventListeners = function () {
    this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, function (data) {
        console.log('layout. data:', data);
        var count = document.getElementsByClassName("shuffle-item--hidden").length;
        console.log(count);
        if (count > 150) {
            $(".img-fluid").addClass("img-big");
        } else {
            $(".img-fluid").removeClass("img-big");
        }
    });

    this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, function (data) {
        console.log('removed. data:', data);
        var count = document.getElementsByClassName("shuffle-item--hidden").length;
        console.log(count);
        if (count > 150) {
            $(".img-fluid").addClass("img-big");
        } else {
            $(".img-fluid").removeClass("img-big");
        }
    });
};
```

My CSS file contains the following:

```
.img-fluid {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.img-big {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

The problem that happens is, when the count is >150, the pictures themselves are getting resized, but they are being cropped.
The result is the following:
https://i.imgur.com/VEAhmLD.gif

Can you point me to the right direction here?

The img elements are displayed like this:

```
 <figure class="picture-item" data-groups='["it"]'>
   <img src="images/georgi-naydenov.jpg" class="img-fluid" data-toggle="popover" alt="...">
   <div class="picture-item__details">
     <figcaption class="picture-item__title">Georgi Naydenov</figcaption>
   </div>
  </figure>
```

I have made a fiddle with just the HTML as I do not want to show the whole javascript file - https://jsfiddle.net/4kdfngrw/

Comment: Please add your HTML code.

Comment: _“Can you point me to the right direction here?”_ - why yes, of course: [mcve] // Impossible to tell why this may happen without you showing us what kind of HTML structure these images are actually contained in, and what formatting gets applied to that.

Comment: Sorry guys, just edited the comment - I left a part of the HTML and Fiddle with the whole HTML